# Pre-Load Points into Google Map API

Tags: google-maps

I'm creating a google map with about 200,000 points.  It takes a while to load the points into the API and then browsing is sluggish.

If not, can someone suggest a better way then this:

I load the points as Lat & Long segments into flightPlanCoordinates and then map them with this code:

```
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: flightPlanCoordinates,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});
```

Is there any way to save the state of a google map you can just reload it without all the processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers have gotten significantly better at handling this over the last few years, but once you hit a few thousand points you're probably better off starting to consider rending your data as image tiles instead of vectors within the browser (although projects like [polymaps](http://polymaps.org/) and others show a lot of promise with complex vector data).

One solution in the context of the Google Maps API (v3) is to create a KML and use a [KmlLayer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers), or else put your data in [Google Fusion Tables](http://google.com/fusiontables) and use the [FusionTablesLayer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#FusionTables).  Either way, your polygons will be rendered by Google's servers as image tiles and place negligible overhead on the browser relative to your current scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Making a map with 200,000 points is not a good idea; you should use fewer points.

It sounds like you're displaying a detailed flight path; you should merge all points within a mile or so to reduce the total number.

Comment: It's really about 200 polygons with 200k points on those polygons.  Any suggests as to how to create those using a better method?